# I have list of student exam detail in Couchbase bucket. Now I have to fetch student list grouped by their class and sum of each subject and total

Tags: couchbase, sql++, couchbase-view, design-documents

I have done this using query but as I have a large amount of data it takes more time. Now I have to pick the data in lesser time using design documents or Indexes. Kindly suggest which will be more efficient and execute with sorter time?

Here is an example:

```
[{"name":"alex","class":2,"english":59,"maths":50,"science":70},
{"name":"ave","class":3,"english":59,"maths":50,"science":70},
{"name":"dany","class":2,"english":59,"maths":50,"science":70}]
```

Excepted result:

```
[{"class":2,"english":118,"maths":100,"science":140},
{"class":3,"english":59,"maths":50,"science":70}]
```

Please give me a better solution to solve this with sample code.

Comment: are you using CouchDB or Couchbase?

Comment: I am using couchbase

Comment: Would you please supply the N1QL query and index that you are currently using?

Comment: I have found the solution with the normal select query as given below